# Can not add or remove body class when using $stateChangeSuccess event from UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is the issue took me about one week to troubleshooting!!! I can not find the answer. So I will share with you guys.

Below is the code. The class `test` will apply to body without any issue if I click Login in /home state.

BUT. If I paste http://localhost:3000/login into browser, it doesn't work at all!

```
angular.module('app').config(function($stateProvider) {

$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/home'
  }).state('login', {
    url: '/login'
  });

}).run(function($rootScope) {

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
    var bodyElem = angular.element(document.body);
    bodyElem.addClass('test');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a fully debug and tracing. I found out the reason. Just simply use `$viewContentLoaded` instead of `$stateChangeSuccess`

Now the code working as expected

```
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
  var bodyElem = angular.element(document.body);
  bodyElem.addClass('test');
});
```

Comment: BTW. `$viewContentLoaded` may fired more than one time depends on the number of views in the state. You have to add more check to ensure your code only add the class once.

Comment: `$viewContentAnimationEnded` is another option